# Why "android:shadowColor" property not support "selector"?

Tags: android, adt, android-xml, android-drawable

Developers Tools:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Juno Release+Android2.2+ADT-21.0.1.zip

Use:
color/tab_color_text_shadow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <item android:color="#f75893"/>

</selector>
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="main_tab_bottom">
 <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/tab_color_text_shadow</item>
 <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
 <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>



<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/main_tab_bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/exam_menu"
    android:tag="radio_button1"
    android:text="检查"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Question:
Why "android:shadowColor" not support "selector"?

adb bugreport:

```
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/color/tab_color_text_shadow.xml"
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java)
02-19 10:41:23.650: E/AndroidRuntime(29865):    at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java)
```

already post to android project , [issue 49793](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=49793).